# How to capture T-SQL output generated by print statement with PHP ODBC client?

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql, odbc

I have a stored procedure that is returning its result using a transact `print` statement to return it's result.

Until now I used the `php_mssql` extension and its `mssql_get_last_message()` function to get the returned text.

As PHP has dropped the support for the mssql extension, I decided to fall back to the `php_odbc` extension.

The problem I face is that I cannot capture the info using `odbc_errormsg()`. Is there a way to retrieve the print message using PHP and ODBC ?

I found some interesting questions dealing with the subject of `print` and `odbc`, but none related to PHP.

- [PRINT statement in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268384/print-statement-in-t-sql)
- [How Can i display the output of SQL “PRINT” Command in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689336/how-can-i-display-the-output-of-sql-print-command-in-c)

PHP code with mssql (works):

```
$query = "exec dbo.PdaBLCreer 12345";
$res = mssql_query($query);
$message = mssql_get_last_message();
```

PHP code with odbc (does not work, $message is always empty):

```
$query = "exec dbo.PdaBLCreer 12345";
$res = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
$message = odbc_errormsg($connection);
```

T-SQL stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.PdaBLCreer
    @iArgument int
AS
BEGIN
    ...
    PRINT @vNr
    RETURN @vNr
END
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: @shivan Here they are ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this workaround. It works for the `return` value of the stored procedure, but not for `print`. Since my stored procedure prints and returns, this allows to get the result from the procedure without modifying it:

Replace old 5.2 PHP code:

```
$query = "exec dbo.PdaBLCreer 12345";
$res = mssql_query($query);
$message = mssql_get_last_message();
```

with this PHP 5.4 code using php_odbc:

```
$query = "DECLARE @return_status int
    EXEC @return_status = dbo.PdaBLCreer 12345
    SELECT 'ReturnStatus' = @return_status";
$res = odbc_exec($connection, $query);
$line = odbc_fetch_array($res);
$message = $line['ReturnStatus'];
```

This solution is limited. It will not work when your query returns a tabular result and a message.

Comment: this solution is a smart workaround actually. Agreed with what you note in the answer, if the Stored Procedure returns a table of results, this won't work. Another stupid workaround I can think of is to output to a file & read it back in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Empty `$message` by `odbc_errmsg()` is good. That means no error.

Please note that "get last message" is different than "get error message". In fact, the 2 MSSQL PHP drivers work differently. You can't expect they return similar results.

Moreover as a side note, `mssql_*` functions are removed in PHP 5.3 . Use `sqlsrv_*` functions ( require additional software installation from Microsoft ) instead. Read [further](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php).

According to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-errormsg.php),

> Returns a string containing the last ODBC error message, or an empty string if there has been no errors.

Comment: You are right, but it doesn't solve the problem. I cannot use sql_srv, because it is not compatible with sql server 2000.

Comment: How else could I return the value ( integer ) from the stored procedure, given that neither print nor return work ?

Comment: Incorrect. `sqlsrv` is compatible with SQL Server 2000. See: http://sqlsrvphp.codeplex.com/discussions/35511

Comment: ODBC driver does NOT support stored procedure. From [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-execute.php), *If you need to call a stored procedure using INOUT or OUT parameters, the recommended workaround is to use a native extension for your database (for example, mssql for MS SQL Server)*

Comment: Yes, sqlsrv was compatible with sql server 2000, but sqlsrv version 3.0, that is the only one compatible with php 5.4 dropped support for sql server 2000.

Comment: I also found an unofficial version, with added compatibility for SQL 2000 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19787528/1951708), but I'm not sure that it is a good idea to rely on it for future proof development

Comment: As a developer, you should setup your own stable production environment. If you need SQL2000, you shouldn't use PHP 5.4 & sqlsrv 3.0. Of course, another choice is to upgrade your SQL server, or switch to MySQL server for better compatibility with PHP.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments.