# PHP 5.6 and SQL Server 2000

Tags: php, sql-server

Is it possible to integrate PHP 5.6 to SQL Server 2000 Or should I downgrade to PHP 4.x to do this?

I cannot update the server version nor can I convert the database to MySQL.

Comment: Have you tried ODBC or [MS sqlsrv drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff657782.aspx)?

Comment: I've read this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783613/how-to-connect-to-mssql-2000-from-php-5-3-and-up) and I guess I cannot connect with the sqlsrv 3.2. The ODBC driver gives me the error _SQL Server does not exist or access denied_ but I've configured my server to allow remote connections and I've put the right IP address of the server. I'm still trying with the ODBC driver tho.

Comment: Why would you want to work with sql server 2000? use at least 2008 version instead. 2000 version is 6 feet under for quite some time now.

Comment: I'd like to work on a newer version of SQL Server, but the server in my office is not being upgraded. So I need to adapt to it.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to connect PHP 5.6 and SQL Server 2000. In Ubuntu, I used mssql functions and unixodbc drivers. In Windows, I used the SQL Server driver and odbc functions. And I could only use native PHP for it. (I tried with CI but it doesn't have the right config for it)

Here's the connection code for Windows:

```
$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=".$server.";Database=".$database.";", $user, $password);
```