# Is it possible to connect to SQL Server 2000 with PHP7?

Tags: ubuntu, pdo, odbc, php-7, sqlsrv

I'm using PHP7 on Ubuntu and the ODBC Driver 13. 
I've tried using PDO and SQLSRV drivers but I keep receiving errors that sql server 2000 is unsupported.

My dilemma is this server is still in production and I have no means to upgrade it but I need to report on it.

Are there any other methods to connect to this server?
I am completely aware that this server is nearly 18 years old.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30721219/php-5-6-and-sql-server-2000 . However, in PHP 7, `mssql` functions are removed and replaced by `sqlsrv` functions.

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried that but as you mentioned it's replaced by sqlsrv and that won't allow me to connect to sql server 2000.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by using an existing SQL Server 2012 instance I had and linking the database. Then using sqlsrv to connect to the 2012 instance and run my select openquery off of that.

This guide below helped.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2015/05/15/how-to-create-a-linked-server-to-sql-2000-from-sql-2012-or-later/